# Aggregating by Patient ID, how do i summarise the total number of each xray type for each patient?

Tags: spss

I have data set up like this;

Patient id...xray type... weight

1.......................1.......................560

1.......................2.......................2400

1.......................2.......................1629

2.......................5.......................716

2.......................1.......................936

2.......................5.......................1271

3.......................2.......................1823

3.......................2.......................2100

This data shows that Patient 1 has had one chest xray(1) and two abdominal xrays (2) etc etc
I was wondering whether its possible to somehow summarise how many of each type of xray each patient has into a different variable column/s?

The output that I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

Weight range - - - - Average Chest X-ray (type 1) - - - - - Average Abdominal X-ray (type 2)

< 750 - - - - - - - - - - - - 11 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 15 - - - - - - -

I was thinking that perhaps a middle table like : 
weight range - - - chest x-ray num - - - chest x-ray count

might help, but I'm not really sure.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Your Data could be restructured. Since that is a rather complex approach you may have to put thome thaught into that.
In the end, you could something like
Patient Chest Adbdomen....Missing
1         1        2...........

Answer (score 0):

There are many things you could do here, but one simple approach would be this.
First, bin the weight variable into, say, quartiles.  Use Transform > Visual Binning for this.  It has has a number of ways to create the bins.

Second, use Analyze > Compare Means > Means and select whatever statistical summaries you want.

With your bin variable, you could also use Split Files (Data > Split File) and then run Frequencies or other summary procedures that will be calculated separately for each split.